# Dropping 'nan' with Pearson's r in scipy/pandas

Tags: pandas, scipy, nan, pearson

Quick question: Is there a way to use 'dropna' with the Pearson's r function in scipy? I'm using it in conjunction with pandas, and some of my data has holes in it. I know you used to be able suppress 'nan' with Spearman's r in [older versions of scipy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.spearmanr.html), but that functionality is now missing.

To my mind, this seems like a disimprovement, so  I wonder if I'm missing something obvious.

My code:

```
for i in range(len(frame3.columns)):    
    correlation.append(sp.pearsonr(frame3.iloc[ :,i], control['CONTROL']))
```

Comment: Yes, you can use `dropna` for that. What's your question, exactly?

Comment: Really? Every time I append it I get an index error. I've added my code above; where's the appropriate place to put it?

Comment: *"...that functionality is now missing."*  Are you referring to the `nan_policy` argument?  That is still in `spearmanr`.  In fact, the link that you referred to as "older versions" is the documentation for the most recent release, 0.18.0.  What version are you using?  Check by running `import scipy; print(scipy.__version__)`

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser I think he might have confused spearman's with pearson's. There is no `nan_policy` for scipy.stats.pearsonr

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use [`np.isnan`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isnan.html) like this:

```
for i in range(len(frame3.columns)):    
    x, y = frame3.iloc[ :,i].values, control['CONTROL'].values
    nas = np.logical_or(x.isnan(), y.isnan())
    corr = sp.pearsonr(x[~nas], y[~nas])
    correlation.append(corr)
```

Comment: I got the error `AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'isnan'`

Comment: @SteveScott: instead of `x.isnan()`, try `np.isnan(x)`

Answer (score 1):

You can also try creating temporary dataframe, and used pandas built-in method for computing pearson correlation, or use the .dropna method in the temporary dataframe to drup null values before using sp.pearsonr

```
for col in frame3.columns:    
     correlation.append(frame3[col].to_frame(name='3').join(control['CONTROL']).corr()['3']['CONTROL'])
```

Comment: This is making some assumptions about joining, eg: the indices are compatible